# Does onDestory() is ensured to be called after finish()?;

Tags: android, ondestroy, activity-finish

I always think finish() will fire onDestory() immediately.But in 4.3 it seems not the truth.
I just want to know in **which condition** it'll happend ?
sorry,I can't put all my code on here.
It confused me a few hours,and I can't find any useful info about it.

Comment: afaik there is not guarantee that onDestroy will always be called, you sohuld try with onStop maybe? also to give u a little bit more of an answer, I think onDestroy is 100% to be called only when system is low on memory/

Comment: No, not onStop(). onPause() is the one he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs:](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

> `onPause()` is the last method that's guaranteed to be called before the process can be killed—if the system must recover memory in an emergency, then `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` might not be called. Therefore, you should use `onPause()` to write crucial persistent data (such as user edits) to storage.

It doesn't matter if you used `finish()` or the system killed your Activity on its own. If the system "wants" to recover memory, there's no guarantee that `onDestroy()` or `onStop()` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no guarantee `onDestroy()` will be called.

The same goes for `onStop()`

What you want instead is `onPause()`

This is true for all versions of Android, going back to 1.0 to the very latest. The [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) can be initially very confusing for beginners. But it's not the beginner's fault, it's the fault of the framework designers.

Another mistake beginners make is to assume that `onResume()` is about resuming the Activity, when in fact it's the UI thread that is resuming while it is in its Activity. This is another point that the documentation goes over and over again, but really, it would have been a lot simpler if the android team had called that method something less ambiguous to begin with.

Comment: You're right about of onStop() and onDestory.but can you show me some info about onResume? what's the meaning of resuming the UI thread only?

Comment: One consequence is that onResume() will also be called at the beginning of an Activity (not just when the Activity resumes). Another consequence is that sometimes some methods need to be called only when the UI is already rendered and ready to be interacted with, otherwise they won't work as originally intended. For instance, in the case of a managed dialog from an Activity, Activity.showDialog() will need to be called as late as onResume() otherwise it won't be able to resize itself properly when there is an orientation change.

Answer (score 1):

First, this answer assumes that you are referring to Android's Activity class and its `finish()` method and `onDestroy()` lifecycle method.

Second, it depends upon your definition of "sure":

Your process could be terminated in between `finish()` and `onDestroy()`, for reasons independent of whatever is triggering the call to `finish()`

A device manufacturer or ROM modder could introduce some screwy change that would break the connection between `finish()` and `onDestroy()`

The battery could go dead in between `finish()` and `onDestroy()`

Etc.

Comment: Or the user could receive a phone call, or the user could press the home button, and an Android system strapped for resources may simply decide to wait between the time it calls finish() and onDestroy() so as no to trigger a stutter in the user experience.

Answer (score -1):

according to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
Will allways be called, 
onDestroy():
*the final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.*

Comment: If you read the docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) you'll see that `onDestroy` is NOT always called.